# How to correctly return my data from AJAX call (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax, angularjs-service

I have a view that calls this function below which makes an AJAX call to our API - this for some reason always returns 'undefined' when I view this in the AngularScope using the Firefox DOM inspection tool.

If I check the Network tab I can see this URL has been called and can see the JSON which I expect, I then want to return the data.words JSON data but this is always returning undefined? If I remove the AJAX call and just  leave in the last return with the 'static' and 'words' in this works as expected, so it is clear to me something about the returning in the AJAX success call doesn't seem to be right... any ideas??

// within a AngularJS service file

```
this.getAccSignoffWords = function() {
    var url = ApiService.getDomain() + 'account/signoff';
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : url
    }).success(function(data) {
        if (data.success) {
            return data.words; // I want to return this JSON to the scope
        }
    }).error(function(data) {
        throw "Failed to get sign-off words";
    })['finally'](function(data) {

    });

    // return [ 'static', 'words' ]; // this line is commented out and only used for testing and is an example of the type of data expected from data.words
}
```

Comment: Try parsing the data in success call back: `data= JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: Hi Nishanth, where should this be placed - shall I remove the current return within the success block

Comment: hmm still no joy using that in the success block.. :(

Comment: your ajax doesn't return anything..that's just a call back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thing is when you are sending the http request, it take some time to process and send data back to your javascript code. but since the javascript is asynchronous, it doesn't wait until response return. so either you can return the whole http request like  **Umakanta Behera** suggested or you can use a callback function to wait unit the response come back.

```
this.getAccSignoffWords = function(callback) {
    var url = ApiService.getDomain() + 'account/signoff';
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : url
    }).success(function(data) {
        if (data.success) {
            callback() data.words
        }
    }).error(function(data) {
        throw "Failed to get sign-off words";
    })['finally'](function(data) {

    });
}
```

call this function like this

```
this.getAccSignoffWords(function(data){
     console.log(data) // your http response 
})
```

Comment: Can you point out where the second 'calling' function goes in relation to my code (is this controller, service, view etc..) thanks

Comment: Call this from ur controller

Answer (score 1):

that's because your ajax doesn't return anything.. if you want to assign it to scope you should be doing:

```
var self = this;
var url = ApiService.getDomain() + 'account/signoff';
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : url
    }).success(function(data) {
        if (data.success) {
            self.getAccSignoffWords = data.words; // I want to return this JSON to the scope
        }
    }).error(function(data) {
        throw "Failed to get sign-off words";
    })['finally'](function(data) {

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not retuning $http result.Could u please give a try to below code.

```
this.getAccSignoffWords = function() {
    var url = ApiService.getDomain() + 'account/signoff';
    return $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : url
    }).success(function(data) {
        if (data.success) {
            return data.words; // I want to return this JSON to the scope
        }
    }).error(function(data) {
        throw "Failed to get sign-off words";
    })['finally'](function(data) {

    });

    // return [ 'static', 'words' ]; // this line is commented out and only used for testing and is an example of the type of data expected from data.words
}
```

Comment: thanks Umakanta although that gives me the same issue, good shot at it though

Comment: doesn't appear to work for me i'm doing something silly i am sure, i will keep on it :)